# Civilization V Patronage social policy tree when playing as Alexander

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

Alexander the Great has the Hellenic League bonus in Civilization V, which means that "City-State influence degrades half as slowly as normal, and it recovers at twice the speed as for other civilizations". If I choose the Patronage social policy tree, which has the initial bonus "Adopting Patronage will cause  Influence with City-States to degrade 25% slower than normal", does this mean that the influence will degrade 75% slower than normal? In other words, are the two effects cumulative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Percent bonuses are additive

If you have racial 50% bonus and 25% social bonus, you should get in the end, as expected a 75% bonus.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/wu2fd/a_question_of_percentages/)